# Determine what project id my App Engine code is running on

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

From within an App Engine app, is there a way to determine the project ID a GAE (App Engine) instance is running on?

I want to access a big query table in the same project that the App Engine instance is running in. I'd rather not hard code it in or include it in another config file if possible.

Edit: forgot to mention that this is from Python

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get a lot of info from environment variables:

```
import os
print os.getenv('APPLICATION_ID')
print os.getenv('CURRENT_VERSION_ID')
print os.environ
```

Answer (score 13):

This is the "official" way:

```
from google.appengine.api import app_identity

GAE_APP_ID = app_identity.get_application_id()
```

See more here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/appidentity/

Answer (score 8):

I tried the other approaches in 2019 using Python3.  So far as I can tell, those approaches are for Python2 (and one for Java).

I was able to accomplish this in Python3 using:

```
import os

app_id = os.getenv('GAE_APPLICATION')
print(app_id)
project_id = os.getenv('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT')
print(project_id)
```

source: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime

Answer (score 5):

I also added an app version, in case you need it too.

```
import com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty;


String appId = SystemProperty.applicationId.get();
String appVersion = SystemProperty.applicationVersion.get();
```