# How to get the ID of the GAE project that a Java app is running in?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a Java app running in Google App Engine. I need to programmatically get the ID of the project it's running as part of, in Java.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552694/determine-what-project-id-my-app-engine-code-is-running-on) explains how to achieve my goals in Python, but that's not Java of course.

[This documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/appidentity) says that I can simply call `ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment().getAppId()`, but this method just returns null in my app.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59416746/how-to-programmatically-get-current-project-id-in-google-cloud-run-api) explains how to get the project ID over an HTTP request, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this in Java without having to manually construct an HTTP request?

Edit: Luyi's answer seems like it's working for most people, but it returns null for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions` helper to get the default project id.
It will provide you some abstraction to be able to retrieve `project-id` depending on your context and current app-engine runtime.

For instance Java11 runtime does not support some old api. And getting `project-id` via requesting metadata by HTTP is a versatile solution.

In this case, `ServiceOptions.getDefaultProjectId` is a good way to keep your code versatile and simple.

[Spring Cloud GCP](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/master/spring-cloud-gcp-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gcp/core/DefaultGcpProjectIdProvider.java) is using this method behind the scene to retrieve `project-id`.

Import `google-cloud-core` dependency :

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.94.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then use `ServiceOptions`:

```java
import com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions;
...

String projectId = ServiceOptions.getDefaultProjectId();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this:

```
import com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty;
    
String appId = SystemProperty.applicationId.get();
```

From SystemProperty you can get other info too, such as Environment and Application Version.